# How to remove underscores in field names with logstash?

Tags: regex, logstash

I'm thinking about using the `mutate` filter and the `rename` option, but I don't know about the corresponding regex to achieve that:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => {
      "any_field_with_underscore" => "anyfieldwithunderscore" # i don't know how to write regex for this ...
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

There no indication in the doc that `rename{}` takes a regexp.

I've seen this done with a `ruby{}` filter.

As requested, here's some *untested* Ruby:

```
begin
    keys = event.to_hash.keys
    keys.each{|key|
        if ( key =~ /_/ )

            newkey = key.gsub(/_/, '')
            event[newkey] = event.remove(key)

        end
    }

rescue Exception => e
    event['logstash_ruby_exception'] = 'underscores: ' + e.message
end
```

Comment: okay... well just to be a bit greedy how would one accomplish it with ruby{}?

Comment: It almost works.  Not a big deal to store the kvs and add them outside of the iteration:   Ruby exception occurred: can't add a new key into hash during iteration {:level=>:error, :file=>"logstash/filters/ruby.rb", :line=>"41", :method=>"filter"}

Comment: That's why it copies the keys to a new variable before the loop.  Maybe you took that out of your code?

Comment: Works perfectly as is for LS < 5.x, But note that direct access to the event object will not work in newer versions because it has been replaced with a pure Java object, and will require access via getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

To build on [Alain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/677561/alain-collins)'s answer,

In Logstash >= 5.x, an event object accessor is enforced:

```
 ruby {

  code => "
        begin
            keys = event.to_hash.keys
            keys.each{|key|
                if ( key =~ /http_/ )

                    newkey = key.gsub(/http_/, '')
                    event.set(newkey, event.remove(key))

                end
            }

        rescue Exception => e
            event.set('logstash_ruby_exception', 'underscores: ' + e.message)
        end
        "
 }

}
```

Also see [this feature request](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5447) that would do the same