# Rename a dynamic field with logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash

I want to use the logstash ruby plugin to rename a dynamic field name.
Specifically I want to strip out dots so I can feed it to Elasticsearch and remove some extra static text

A field name like this

```
foo.bar.Host11.x.y.uptime => 37
```

would become

```
host11_uptime => 37
```

or even better to split into seperate fields

```
host => 11

uptime => 37
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [some general code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068169/how-to-remove-underscores-in-field-names-with-logstash/31120218#31120218) to loop across fields in ruby.  You could then split the field name to create the one (or more) that you wanted.