# Logstash - Convert Field Names to Lowercase

Tags: logstash

I am processing http logs and converting querystring parameters to fields.

```
kv
{
  source => "uriQuerystring"
  field_split => "&"
  target => "uriQuerystringKeys"
}
```

However because callers are using mixed case parameters, I end up with numerous duplicates.

eg:  `uriQuerystringKeys.apiKey`, `uriQuerystringKeys.ApiKey`, `uriQuerystringKeys.APIKey`

What do I need to do in my logstash configuration to convert all these field names to lowercase?

I see there's an [open issue for this feature](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2526) to be implemented in Logstash, but it's incomplete. There's a suggestion for some ruby code to be directly executed, but it looks like this converts *all* fields (not just ones of a certain prefix).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068169/how-to-remove-underscores-in-field-names-with-logstash/31120218#31120218) that contains the basic code you would need.

You can see a conditional inside the loop, which you could use to enforce the prefix limitations on the fields.