# Simplify multiple conditions in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have the following conditions multiple times in my logstash.conf.

Is they some way to remove the duplication ?

```
if [body][content][totalConsumers] != "null" {
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["[body][content][totalConsumers]"]
    }
}
if [body][content][newConsumers] != "null" {
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["[body][content][newConsumers]"]
    }
}
if [body][content][daysActiveConsumers] != "null" {
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["[body][content][daysActiveConsumers]"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to generically loop through fields in logstash is through the use of the ruby{} filter.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068169/how-to-remove-underscores-in-field-names-with-logstash/31120218#31120218) should get you started.