# How to remove the prefix underscores from field keys in logstash using regex

Tags: regex, logstash, kibana

As Kibana requires prefix underscores in the field keys- [link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2551) (this issue seems unresolved), I am not able to process the field key values that come with default starting underscores (eg-journald logs for docker) in Kiabana. I am using logstash currently to push the logs to elasticsearch. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068169/how-to-remove-underscores-in-field-names-with-logstash) that uses ruby filter to remvove **all underscores**, but I guess this method would make my consumer very slow.

Is there a way to remove the prefix underscores from all the field names  using the power of regex in logstash?

For example -

```
_HELO: World
```

should now change to be:

```
HELLO: World
```

probably by using a different pluggin than `ruby`

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I am not using fluentd for this. I am using fluentbit for my configuration. Thanks for replying thouhg.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-prefix) to remove prefix from keys using regex. It helps automatically parse messages (or specific event fields) which are of the `foo=bar` variety, and have configuration option `remove_char_key` that is used to remove string of characters from the key.

for instance, this will remove `<`, `>`, `[, ]` and `,` characters from keys

```
filter {
  kv {
    remove_char_key => "<>\[\],"
  }
}
```

Another option is `remove_char_value` which can be used to remove characters from values

for instance, this will remove `<`, `>`, `[, ]` and `,` characters from values

```
filter {
  kv {
    remove_char_value => "<>\[\],"
  }
}
```

These can be used with `source` to perform `key=value` searching on

```
filter { 
  kv { 
    source => "message" 
    remove_char_value => "<>\[\],"
    remove_char_key => "<>\[\],"
  } 
}
```

Please also have a look at [trim_key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-trim_key) and [trim_value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-trim_value) options

Comment: I tried the trim_key option but it did not work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove an underscore that's the first character of a field called `fieldname`, you can use:

```
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "fieldname", "^_", ""
    ]
  }
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub

Comment: No. I want to do that for all the fieldname values that start with an `_`. Thanks for your answer though. I made the question more clear.

Comment: @Akash I was not sure it would be useful, but I preferred to write it just in case. The only solution (without `ruby`) I can think of would be to know the field names in advance and use mutate.copy. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to resort to a `ruby` filter that looks for keys that start with `_` and basically renames them (copy value to a new key and then remove original key):

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      event.to_hash.keys.each { |k|
         if k.start_with?('_')
          event.set(k[1,-1],event.get(k))
          event.remove(k)
       end
     }
   "
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But as already mentioned I am not looking for a ruby filter. Seems it's not possible without it.

Comment: The answer you linked to is slow because it uses gsub specifically. Besides any existing filter is going to written in ruby. And logstash is good about compiling in the config file.